# Probability of hammering the insect

Tags: probability, geometry, contest-math

> A $20cm\times20cm$ square board is hit by a hammer having circular base of radius 2cm. An insect lies at the centre of the board. What's the probability that the insect will be hit? (The hammer hits completely inside the square board)

**My Attempt:**

$$\frac{\pi(2)^2}{20\times20}=\frac{\pi}{100}$$

But it is not the correct answer.

How to do this question?

**Edit:**

I appeared in an exam today. The question paper was taken back. I have reproduced the above question from memory. There is a good possibility I am missing out on important technicalities. Sorry about that. If you can help me smooth out the question, that will be very helpful. Thanks.

There were four options. I remember only two. $\dfrac{\pi}{4}, \dfrac{\pi}{25}$.

Comment: The hammer hit has to land entirely inside the square board surface? It does make a difference in the calculations.

Comment: This is not clear.  How do we randomly determine what area gets hit?  Depending on the response to this, the final answer will change.

Comment: @Zima thanks. Edited.

Comment: Given that the entire hammer face fits in the circle, the center of the hammer blow must be at least $2$ from the circumference of the big circle.

Comment: See for example [Bertrand's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)) emphasizing that ambiguously defined random scenarios can give different results to very similarly worded questions.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks. I was not aware of it. I have edited my post. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:  The center of the hammer will land in all legal points within the square with "*uniform probability*".  A "*legal point*" here would be one such that the hammer head does not extend beyond the square.

In such a scenario, you can see that the center of the hammer head can not then land within 2 cm of any edge of the square and as such will land on a point within a $16\text{cm}\times 16\text{cm}$ square (*having marked a 2cm strip along each side as being off-limits*).

We have then a total area of $256~\text{cm}^2$ that the center of the hammer could land on.  Of this area, $4\pi~\text{cm}^2$ of it would be in the circle of radius two surrounding the center, noting that the insect is hit if and only if the center of the hammer lands within a circle of radius $2\text{cm}$ from the center.  Taking the ratio and simplifying gives the answer

$$\dfrac{4\pi}{256}=\dfrac{\pi}{64}$$

Comment: Thank you, means a lot!

Comment: @aarbee Per your latest edit, with the center of the hammer being restricted to hitting within the square and no concern is placed on whether the rest of the hammer remains within the square, and assuming uniform distribution to where the center of the hammer hits, then the answer of $\frac{\pi}{100}$ would have been correct.  Given that you have reason to believe that is an incorrect answer, then the assumption may have been wrong.

Comment: Seems like I messed up again. I'll revert the edit and then will think about my possible doubts here, if any.

Comment: I think I got it this time, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The  danger zone for the insect is a disk with radius $4$ cm (the diameter of the base of the hammer), not $2$.

Besides, but it has smaller importance, the reference zone shouldn't be the square but a rounded version of it, with 4 little areas removed, with a total area of $4^2-\pi 2^2$ (to be subtracted to $20^2$). Do you see why ?

Therefore, your result should be :

$$\frac{16\pi}{384+4\pi}$$

Comment: I guess that option was not there. (Please check my edited post)

Comment: Sorry, I had worded it wrongly earlier.

Comment: Under the most natural interpretations and assumptions, the probability distribution of whether a position is struck at all by any part of the hammer head is not going to be uniform.  It is far less likely for a position at the edge to be hit than one in the center since you can hit a space on the edge in only a small number of ways while if the position were in the interior of the square you can approach from many angles.  I see no other reasonable interpretation that leads to the ability to calculate an answer other than mine where we assume the center of the hammer's position to be uniform.

Comment: Yes, the area which may be struck at all by any part of a hammer is $384+4\pi$, but that is the right answer to the wrong question.

Comment: @JMoravitz Another issue to be taken into consideration : the insect might belong to an endangered species, then according to the person who holds the hammer, knowing that a good 30% are eco-conscious...